# dealing with static files in Django

Tags: python, django

Currently I have my settings.py regarding static files set up like so

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

From reading the documentation and various blogs my understanding is that `STATIC_ROOT` is where the static files go. It is the absolute path to the directory where `collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment (OUTPUT). I am not sure what to put this value as

For `STATICFILES_DIR` This setting defines the additional locations the static files app will traverse if the FileSystemFinder finder is enabled. So I would NEED a `STATICFILES_FINDER` field in my `settings.py` and in that field would be

```
('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')
```

However, by default `STATICFILES_DIR` is not included in my `settings.py` so I added it in.

For `STATIC_URL` is the URL to use when referring to static files located in STATIC_ROOT. I simply left it as the default setting because I am not sure how edit this.

I am not sure how to edit my settings.py regarding static files in order to display them onto a webpage. What is a "Best Practices" way to include static files onto a webpage?

ex: `{% static "static/css/default.css" %}`

I read a bit about namespacing as well but I am confused about this too

ex:

```
STATICFILES_DIR = (
    ("asserts",  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
    )
```

Comment: Did you forget adding your app into INSTALLED_APPS? Check this out http://runnable.com/U0TxZ0j4By9YfeT4/django_working_static_files-for-python

Comment: @muzhig it was included

Comment: @muzhig that site is pretty cool!!

Comment: I serve static files like described in this website: http:/www.hasnath.net/blog/serving-static-files-css-js-images-in-django-the-best-way

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be keeping each app's static files in it's own 'static' dir and running  `manage.py collect_static` each time some static file changes.

Then, if you use *default storage* your files would be copied into STATIC_ROOT directory.
(But you might use custom storage, for ex for storing static files on Amazon S3 cloud)

And finally, STATIC_URL defines how your static files would be accessible from outside. In case of django dev server- it has static files app, that serves them under STATIC_URL location. In case of production server you definitely want to serve static files with either nginx/apache or with amazon S3/cloudfront (or other cloud services). In case ouf serving with nginx/apache, you must set STATIC_URL so `{% static "static/css/default.css" %}` will be replaced with the url relative to STATIC_ROOT, at the same time you should have this STATIC_URL location overriden in nginx/apache settings, so when final user tries to access it, it gets static file served w/o even touching django. In case of custom storage- this storage might provide it's own url (to S3 cloud for ex).

Comment: keeping each app's static files in it's own 'static' dir is not a best practice, it' s an anti-pattern

Comment: @Leonardo.Z WAT? Could you point any reliable source explaining this?
Here is mine: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files "Store your static files in a folder called static in your app"

Comment: same url your posted, Static file namespacing

Comment: Static files usually can be used cross multiple django apps. If we use a button pic, it's better to put it under /static/img/buttons/xxx.img that /static/appname/xxxx

Comment: @muzhig I am having a bit of trouble following. Could we start a chat room to help me clear this up?

Comment: @Leonardo.Z Ah, that one is related to previous paragraph. It says "Your project will probably *also* have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app." so this block is relevant only for static files which are n't related to one single app.

Comment: @muzhig But in most cases, static files are used in multiple apps. It's important to keep the ui consistent.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50518/django-static-files @Leonardo.Z can join too